# How to remove particular lines containing specific symbol using AWK / perl

Tags: perl, awk

I have multiple files with .txt extension, In all files some lines having "?" symbol, so how to remove those whole line in all files using single AWK/perl command

I used following command:

perl -pi -e "s/\?//g" *.txt

but it remove only ? symbol not whole line, so please help me to remove whole line contain "?" symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One perly way:

```
perl -ni -e 'next if /\?/; print' *.txt
```

The `-n` flag loops over the file the same way as `-p`, however it doesn't automatically print the line; it leaves that responsibility to you. So what we do is loop over all lines, skip the ones with a `?` with `next()`, and print all others.

Comment: Dont need the next `perl -ni -e 'print if !/\?/' *.txt`

Comment: You're right. I don't know why I didn't do it that way. Still pretty early in the AM ;)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for a single file is `grep -Fv \? old_file > new_file`. You could also use `sed -i '/\?/d' old_file`. If you want to handle all files at once, without writing a loop, the second option is more convenient, since `sed` can handle multiple files at once.

Comment: @stevieb I have amended my answer.

Comment: sed -i '/\?/d' file not working,  sed: 1: "ff": invalid command code

Comment: @mona So you are using OSX, are you?

Comment: Don't escape the `?` in sed, it's an ERE metachar, not BRE, so by escaping it you'll activate it's ERE properties in some seds. Just leave it as-is `sed '/?/d'`. For the grep you don't need `-F` as, again, it's just a literal character in a BRE and quote it, don't escape it: `grep -v '?' file`.